# How can I select two columns data on one condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table [see the Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a63c3/1). It contains details of user's size on 3 different visits. My question is how can I select the minimum size between the three size columns for each user and the respective date from the 3 dates column of the minimum size? I can get minimum size from the following query I guess but respective date, not sure?

```
Select 
    Name,
    Case 
        When Size1 < Size2 And Size1 < Size3 Then Size1
        When Size2 < Size1 And Size2 < Size3 Then Size2 
        Else Size3
    End As MinSize
From
    Test
```

This is what I am looking for

```
╔══════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ name ║   visit    ║ minSize ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║ ABC  ║ 2014-02-01 ║     100 ║
║ DEF  ║ 2014-01-01 ║     100 ║
║ GHI  ║ 2014-02-01 ║      50 ║
║ JKL  ║ 2014-03-01 ║     300 ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Is there any chance you could normalise the database? I.e. have username, visit, size as the columns.

Comment: I think not, Data for each visit is recorded seperately

Comment: How about Cross Join with itself?

Comment: What if the size is the same on two or more visits? Which date would you select then?

Comment: @Nimko *"Data for each visit is recorded seperately"* is in direct contradiction the the SQL Fiddle you linked to.

Comment: @Andrew, sorry I mean stored in the same table. The first one. I think I also need to use isNull function to cope with null because size value cannot be compared with null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
CREATE TABLE test
  (
     username VARCHAR(50),
     visit1   DATETIME,
     visit2   DATETIME,
     visit3   DATETIME,
     size1    INT,
     size2    INT,
     size3    INT
  );
INSERT INTO test
VALUES     ( 'ABC',
             '2014-01-01',
             '2014-02-01',
             '2014-03-01',
             200,
             100,
             300 );
INSERT INTO test
VALUES     ( 'EFG',
             '2014-01-01',
             '2014-02-01',
             '2014-03-01',
             100,
             200,
             300 );
INSERT INTO test
VALUES     ( 'HIJ',
             '2014-01-01',
             '2014-02-01',
             '2014-03-01',
             400,
             50,
             100 );
INSERT INTO test
VALUES     ( 'KLM',
             '2014-01-01',
             '2014-02-01',
             '2014-03-01',
             600,
             100,
             300 );

SELECT UserName,
           CASE
             WHEN Size1 < Size2
                  AND Size1 < Size3 THEN Visit1
             WHEN Size2 < Size1
                  AND Size2 < Size3 THEN Visit2
             ELSE visit3
           END AS Date,
           CASE
             WHEN Size1 < Size2
                  AND Size1 < Size3 THEN Size1
             WHEN Size2 < Size1
                  AND Size2 < Size3 THEN Size2
             ELSE Size3
           END AS MinSize
    FROM   Test
```

Comment: I just found that there are some null values and size value is not compared with null. Any suggestions?

Comment: If size1 and size2 are the same size3 will be chosen even if it's higher.

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot your 3 visits into 3 rows using a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx), then select the top 1 in order of size:

```
SELECT  t.username,
        ms.Visit,
        MinSize = ms.Size
FROM    Test AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 m.visit, m.size
            FROM    (VALUES 
                        (1, t.visit1, t.size1), 
                        (2, t.visit2, t.size2), 
                        (3, t.visit3, t.size3)
                    ) AS m (VisitNo, Visit, Size)
            ORDER BY m.Size 
        ) AS ms;
```

**EDIT**

If you have more columns, just add more rows to your table valued constructor

```
SELECT  t.username,
        ms.Visit,
        MinSize = ms.Size
FROM    Test AS t
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 m.visit, m.size
            FROM    (VALUES 
                        (1, t.visit1, t.size1), 
                        (2, t.visit2, t.size2), 
                        (3, t.visit3, t.size3), 
                        (4, t.visit4, t.size4),  -- New values added for more columns
                        (5, t.visit5, t.size5), 
                        (6, t.visit6, t.size6), 
                        (7, t.visit7, t.size7)
                    ) AS m (VisitNo, Visit, Size)
            ORDER BY m.Size 
        ) AS ms;
```

Comment: It was only a sample table, will your query hold for a long table?

Comment: I see no reason why not. The best way to found out though would be to try it.

Comment: Sorry I am newbie. I coudnt get the second part. Can you please update the query when there is onne table of test with columns username, siz1, size2, size3, size4, size5, size6, size7, visit1, visit2, visit3, visit4, visit5, visit6, visit7. I think I dont need values etc Am I?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit more complex than it needs to be, but one option is to normalize the data using queries unioned together, and then use either row_number, rank, or dense_rank to number the rows:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, r = row_number() over (partition by username order by size) 
    from (
       select username, visit1 as visit, size1 as size from test
       union all
       select username, visit2 as visit, size2 as size from test
       union all
       select username, visit3 as visit, size3 as size from test
    ) u
) t
where r = 1;
```

If the size values can be null you should use isnull or coalesce in the innermost queries.

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a63c3/11)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
declare  @test table
(
  username varchar(50),
  visit1 datetime,
  visit2 datetime,
  visit3 datetime,
  size1 int,
  size2 int,
  size3 int
  );

  insert into @test Values( 'ABC', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', 200, 100, 300 );
  insert into @test Values( 'EFG', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', 100, 200, 300 );
  insert into @test Values( 'HIJ', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', 400, 50, 100 );
  insert into @test Values( 'KLM', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', 600, 100, 300 );

--select * from @test

SELECT username,  Minvisit,MinSize
FROM @test
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) Minvisit FROM (VALUES (visit1), (visit2), (visit3)) AS a(d)) A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(d) MinSize FROM (VALUES (size1), (size2), (size3)) AS a(d)) B
```

Comment: Not getting the proper date.